How do you post a picture of an unidentified bag?
I have a bag but no directions.  How do I post a pic of the bag?

When you are posting your question you should be able to see a picture icon in the formatting bar of the text box:

This will allow you to upload an image from your computer to our servers, or link to an image on another website (we'll make a copy of the image on our servers too I think).
How you get the image on to your computer is a slightly different question, and one that's out of scope of this site - it depends on what you're able to take the picture with - however most phones for example will allow you to sync with either a cloud storage provider or with your computer, or have a way to share the image via email - at which point you should be able to save it to your computer and then upload it.

It's worth noting that you can't upload images until you have 10 reputation. Users without this much reputation will have to post a link to the image hosted elsewhere.

Hmm - not sure that's the case - or atleast if it is, then it's a penalty for signing up - An unregistered user (me in Chrome incognito) was able to upload an image just fine: http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/q/335/56

There is a privilege at 100 rep that allows images in chat, but it looks like images are allowed earlier now - there's nothing in the New User Restrictions about images, just "more than two hyperlinks" - which would include image links, but one or two images would be fine.

Interesting. For some reason I thought this was rep limited. I wonder if this changed at some point. There are still questions like this one that ask about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183926/reputation-10-to-post-images
